# MS Word - excel cell, "update link" changes format. How to preserve format?

Tags: excel, ms-word

I have a MS word paragraph with a few text strings linked to excel cells. When I "update link", the cell loses its formatting, with paragraphs added before and after that cell. Checking the "Preserve formatting after update" option in Word does not seem to work. "Keep source formatting" and "Merge formatting" pasting options give me the same result with this.

I checked the source code in Word with alt+f9, and searched for something to add to it

```
{ LINK Excel.Sheet.12 "Book1" "Sheet1!R1C1" \a \f 4 \h \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

I followed these instructions: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/220526, by adding * CHARFORMAT \ to the link source code. It did not work, likely because the instructions are for Office 2000 and I have 2010.

Anyone have a solution to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this with:

Home (tab) > Paste > Paste Options > Paste Special > Paste Link > Unformatted text