# Excel cell linked to MSWord causes line to lose alignment

Tags: excel, hyperlink, ms-word, ms-office

Not sure if I can explain this effectively, but I am trying to link an excel cell to a particular sentance of a word document embedded as an object. Problem is the moment I link the cell (Link and keep source formating), the words after the link shift to the next line. For example:

**Sentence before link:**

"This is a line XXX of the document."

**Sentence after linking cell (cell A1) to "XXX":**

"This is a line

XXX

of the document."

How can I keep the sentence intact while still updating XXX with the contents of the linked cell. I am on MS Office 2013

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** OK, so to clarify, in my excel workbook I have added a Word document as an object to sheet2. This word document contains a line similar to the example above with XXX in bold. A cell in sheet1 is linked to this XXX of the sheet2 word document using the "Link and keep source formating" paste option. This cell is also formated/set to Bold any character entered onto it.

Using the solution here [MS Word - excel cell, "update link" changes format. How to preserve format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358520/ms-word-excel-cell-update-link-changes-format-how-to-preserve-format?rq=1) works but loses the Bold format of the original text that was contained in the cell from sheet1, hence why I was trying to use "Link and keep source formating". I need a solution that will preserve the original formating of the cell.

Comment: Are you linking part of a cell's content? Can you outline the exact steps you have taken to link a cell to a Word object? It's not quite clear.

Comment: @teylyn . Excel Sheet2 has a Word Document embedded.I copy a cell from Sheet1 and paste it to a line containing XXX in the Sheet2 Word document (I choose the "Link and keep source formating" option). The alighnment is fine if I use the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358520/ms-word-excel-cell-update-link-changes-format-how-to-preserve-format?rq=1 , but I unfortunatly lose the "Bold" formatting of the text, so I need a way to preserve the "Bolded" text. Thanks

Comment: please edit your question. Don't put clarification in the comments.